# Looping through API JSON data in nodejs

Tags: node.js, json

Good afternoon,

I am getting data like this:

```
{
        "abcxxxx": {
            "a": ["1.91500", "646", "646.000"],
            "b": ["1.91000", "1614", "1614.000"],
            "c": ["1.92000", "311.93866943"],
            "v": ["45819.50257068", "46925.18489136"],
            "p": ["1.95692", "1.95993"],
            "t": [171, 198],
            "l": ["1.88400", "1.88400"],
            "h": ["2.07200", "2.10900"],
            "o": "2.07200"
        },
        "xxabcx": {
            "a": ["2.16900", "190", "190.000"],
            "b": ["2.16500", "1614", "1614.000"],
            "c": ["2.17000", "3.72887356"],
            "v": ["55632.25862374", "61690.32296177"],
            "p": ["2.19382", "2.20956"],
            "t": [180, 219],
            "l": ["2.12200", "2.12200"],
            "h": ["2.33400", "2.37300"],
            "o": "2.33400"
        },
        "xabcxxx": {
            "a": ["288.29000", "13", "13.000"],
            "b": ["285.88000", "11", "11.000"],
            "c": ["296.27000", "0.06730786"],
            "v": ["8.07845659", "9.84300657"],
            "p": ["290.60752", "294.72859"],
            "t": [20, 23],
            "l": ["286.80000", "286.80000"],
            "h": ["300.69000", "318.03000"],
            "o": "295.34000"
        },
        "cbaxxxx": {
            "a": ["0.06590", "34", "34.000"],
            "b": ["0.06570", "1", "1.000"],
            "c": ["0.06630", "0.13952532"],
            "v": ["283.56565705", "449.03574017"],
            "p": ["0.06570", "0.06574"],
            "t": [62, 94],
            "l": ["0.06380", "0.06380"],
            "h": ["0.06630", "0.06630"],
            "o": "0.06450"
        }
```

The actual data is a lot longer than this (around 750 objects)
I need to be able to loop through the data and get the Key i.e abcxxxx and some of the sub items from said Key.
What is the best way to do this?

thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: If it's a plain JS-object then it's just `obj['abcxxxx'].a` or is it a string?

Comment: Could you give an example of what you would like the output to look like? Are you wanting all of the objects, but each objects properties have been filtered?

Comment: Like @Anatoly and Matt Davis mentioned, can you give an example of the output and more clarification?

Comment: It's as simple as @Anatoly said. To get "some of the sub items from said Key", do `const {key1, key2, key3} = myObj.abcxxxx; console.log(key1, key2, key3);`

Comment: The data I would like to get should simply be assigned to variables and then saved to a database. So ideally it should look something like this:
id = abcxxxx, a = 2.16900, b= 2.16500 
Jut as a little more info there is no way of know the data that is coming as it might change at any point or data will be removed or added.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think it looks cleaner using a loop:

```js
const data = {
  'abc': {
    'd': ['154', '132', '125'],
    'e': ['1544', '132', '125'],
    'f': ['1524', '1532', '1265']
  },
  'ghi': {
    'd': ['154', '132', '125'],
    'e': ['1544', '132', '125'],
    'k': ['1524', '1532', '1265']
  }
}

const transformedData = {}
for (const [key, innerObject] of Object.entries(data)) {
  const { d, e } = innerObject // Properties to keep
  transformedData[key] = { d, e }
}

console.log(transformedData)
```

If you wanted to use [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), something like this:

```js
const data = {
  'abc': {
    'd': ['154', '132', '125'],
    'e': ['1544', '132', '125'],
    'f': ['1524', '1532', '1265']
  },
  'ghi': {
    'd': ['154', '132', '125'],
    'e': ['1544', '132', '125'],
    'k': ['1524', '1532', '1265']
  }
}

const transformedDataArray = Object.entries(data).map(([key, innerObject]) => {
  const filteredInnerObject = Object.entries(innerObject).filter(([key, value]) => {
    const propertiesToKeep = ['d', 'e']
    return propertiesToKeep.includes(key)
  })
  return [key, Object.fromEntries(filteredInnerObject)]
})
const transformedDataObject = Object.fromEntries(transformedDataArray)

console.log(transformedDataObject)
```

Although I would probably extract this into a `filterSubObjects` function or something similar.